# Bind +/- images to slider?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Hi I have an image of a '-' to the left of my slider, and an image of a '+' to the right.

How do I bind these images such that if they are clicked on they will increase or decrease the slider by my value of SMALLCHANGE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mind that the easiest way is to just name your Slider, handle the Image.MouseLeftButtonUp in the UserControl and change its value in code behind. If you doesn't plan to reuse this behavior, there is no need to do any further.

To make this behavior reusable, there are several approaches. Initially I'd suggest using a [EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979699%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in the image with a [CallMethodAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.callmethodaction%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx) bound to the Slider, but the Slider does not has methods like LargeIncrement, SmallIncrement, LargeDecrement, SmallDecremenet. You could subclass it and implement these methods yourself, though.

Another option is to create an [AttachedProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903943%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) like "IncrementSlider" to the Image (or any FrameworkElement), which would receive a Slider instance through a ElementName binding. In the PropertyChangedCallback (see [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/Silverlight2/archive/2008/12/24/understanding-dependency-properties-in-silverlight.aspx)) of the [PropertyMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertymetadata%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), you could subscribe to the MouseLeftButtonUp event of the control and modify the Slider. You could create other attached properties as well, like "DecrementSlider", "SmallIncrementSlider", as well.

A better solution than the AttachedProperty in this case would be an [AttachedBehavior](http://wildermuth.com/2009/5/16/Writing_Behaviors_for_Silverlight_3_-_Part_1). You can create a behavior to a FrameworkElement (or just Image) with a Slider property and other control properties, like "IncrementOrDecrement" and "SmallOrLarge". In the behavior's OnAttached method you would subscribe to the MouseLeftButtonUp of the control to update the Slider (if there is one available). You could then attach the behavior to the Images, bind the Slider property of the behavior to the desired Slider, and configure it to each of them, to increment or decrement in large or small steps.

Comment: Thanks. Lots to try there. This worked too: `Private Sub ImageEasyMinus_MouseLeftButtonDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles ImageEasyMinus.MouseLeftButtonDown
        sliderEasy.Value -= sliderEasy.SmallChange
    End Sub

    Private Sub ImageEasyPlus_MouseLeftButtonDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles ImageEasyPlus.MouseLeftButtonDown
        sliderEasy.Value += sliderEasy.SmallChange
    End Sub`